# Is there an easier way to do this?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am looping through a listbox, and I need to get the same value you would get if you did .selectvalue, but without selecting the row. This is how I am doing it now, and it seems dumb.

```
    For intCtr = 0 To lstUserRoleAll.Items.Count -1 
        lstUserRoleAll.SelectedIndex = intCtr
        InsertUserRoles(lstUserRoleAll.SelectedValue)
    Next
```

I have read that `lstUserRoleAll.Items(intCtr).value` should work, but value isn't a member of that. Also, `lstUserRoleAll.Items(intCtr).tostring` gets me the text "System.Data.DataRowView".

Surely there is a better way to do this.

[image]

Here is the code that I use to add the rows:

```
        Dim rsSelectedGroups As DataTable
        strSQL = "SELECT UID, Name "
        [Rest of query]
        rsSelectedGroups = DataAccess.GetDataTable(strSQL)
        lstUserRoleCurrent.DataSource = rsSelectedGroups
        lstUserRoleCurrent.ValueMember = "UID"
        lstUserRoleCurrent.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Comment: Yes, I did notice the count-1 error and fixed it. However, I am most certainly using a listbox. I can add an image to the post if that is possible.

Comment: The error you get from `lstUserRoleAll.Items(intCtr).ToString` indicated that the item's value is of the type `System.Data.DataRowView`. You will need to extract the information you want from the `DataRowView`. Also, your `For` loop needs to end at `lstUserRoleAll.Items.Count - 1` not `lstUserRoleAll.Items.Count`.

Comment: I deleted my first comment as I realised that I was wrong to say that you were not using a `ListBox`. The problem is that the values in your `ListBox` are of the type `DataRowView`. What type is the `InsertUserRoles` method expecting?

Comment: Can you show how listbox populated with data?

Comment: Added the populate code. It occured to me that the 'System.Data.DataRowView' is returning a reference to the DataTable maybe?

Comment: Yes, that is what is is doing. It is returning a reference to a row in the datatable that corresponds to the row in the listbox. Adding the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I populated the listbox with a datatable, the following code works. I did not realize that is what was being returned.

```
    For intCtr = 0 To lstUserRoleAll.Items.Count
        InsertUserRoles(lstUserRoleAll.Items(intCtr).Item("UID"))
    Next
```

Comment: what you showed in the original code is setting a displaymember and valuemember on another listbox. Not the listbox you're using in the loop. `lstUserRollCurrent` and `lstUserRollAll`

Comment: Yeah, I copied the wrong one. It is the same code to fill the correct one though. I am basically using 2 listboxes to move values from one box to the other using a 'move all' button. The solution above is still correct.